# Visual Studio 2013 opening right click context menu removes selection of text

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Recently our group has updated to Visual Studio 2013 and we have run into a problem that is driving us insane.

Whenever we have a .cpp file open in the editor we have problems right clicking on highlighted text. If we select text and then right click to open the context menu, the text selection is removed and any associated text options are grayed out. This happens regardless if we right click with the mouse or use the keyboard shortcut to open the menu. Copying and cutting with keyboard shortcuts still works, but as we are using Visual Assist X, all our refactoring options are useless. This behavior is only replicated in .cpp files.

We've noticed similar behavior across different machines and have even removed Visual Assist X to ensure it was not the culprit. I've searched through the Visual Studio options, but have not been able to find anything that could be causing this behavior. After finding nothing through google any help would be greatly appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to run Visual Studio in safe mode (Devenv.exe /SafeMode) to check if your problem is caused by a third-party extension https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The behavior worked correctly in debug mode suggesting we still had an extension installed. We narrowed it down to an internal company extension that we had completely forgotten about was installed.